Why does this sed command not work with "?" and "+"?
I'm trying to filter IP addresses from the ip a command via sed. When I write inet6* it works. When I write inet6? it doesn't find the match.
With *:
$ ip a | sed -ne 's,^ *inet6* \([^ /]*\).*$,\1,p'
 05:06:33 
127.0.0.1
::1
192.168.43.222
fe80::df04:ee5d:a05f:ba1

With ?:
$ ip a | sed -ne 's,^ *inet6? \([^ /]*\).*$,\1,p'
 05:07:39 

When I try to run with + instead of * it doesn't work either:
$ ip a | sed -ne 's,^ *inet6* \([^ /]+\).*$,\1,p'
 05:35:21 

Does sed work with ? or +? Or does it only work with *?

See also ip -6 -j address | jq -r '.[].addr_info[].local' or ip -6 a | grep -Po '^ +inet6 \K[^/ ]+'

In a POSIX basic regular expression, which is what sed uses by default, the ? character matches a literal question mark, and + matches a plus sign.  If you want to optionally match one 6 character, then use 6\{0,1\} (easily generalised to 6\{1,\} to be the same as 6+ in an extended expression).
You could also switch to using POSIX extended regular expressions with -E and use 6? as you seem used to do (you would need to change your capture group from \(...\) to (...) too):
ip a | sed -n -E 's/^ *inet6? ([^ /]*).*/\1/p'

Also note that 6* would match the empty string and any length of a run of 6 characters.
See also:

Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?

